# Neovim: external C++ Library Header file parsing not working

Tags: neovim, lunarvim, clangd

I am using Neovim (LunarVim IDE layer), I want to work with 'openFrameworks' library. To not get linter warning on header file includes (look at example below), I am adding all possible header files to my `$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` and `$LIBRARY_PATH` (code shown below).

Is there a better way I can achieve my LSP knowing the header file contents? Vs-Code somehow achieves all that.

I want to achieve this in Neovim. In this temporary fix, whenever a new header is not in path, I have to `find` it in the library folder and add to my `~/.bashrc`, so I am struggling.

Please help.

The warnings:
[image: warnings-on-neovim-linter-header-files-includes]

The annoying temporary fix, is there anything better that I can do?

```bash
# ~/.bashrc

# openFrameworks
openFrameworks="/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/openframeworks/0.12.0/of_v0.12.0_osx_release"
include_dirs=(
    "/libs/openFrameworks/"
    "/libs/openFrameworks/math"
    "/libs/openFrameworks/utils"
    
    ...

    "/libs/uriparser/include"
    "/libs/glm/include"
    "/libs/FreeImage/include"
)

include_path=""
for dir in "${include_dirs[@]}"; do
    include_path+=":${openFrameworks}/${dir}"
done

export LIBRARY_PATH="$include_path:$LIBRARY_PATH"
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$include_path:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"
```

I had tried [`bear`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39910/how-to-add-bits-stdc-h-header-file-in-clangd-installed-through-mason-neovim), but I am getting the following error:

`RPC[Error] code_name = UnknownErrorCode, message = "Failed to parse includes"`

[image: RPC[Error] code_name = UnknownErrorCode, message = "Failed to parse includes"]

Edit1: Also, although the linter errors on header includes have gone away, the LSP features like autocompletion etc, are not working. How do I let my editor (Neovim - LunarVim) know about those header files, or should I give up and switch to an IDE?

Edit2: related: (not fixed)[https://neovim.discourse.group/t/lsp-rpc-error-codes-printed-at-neovim-exit-starting-from-0-8-0/3736]

Comment: Would [that](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/42564/23502) answer help you?

Comment: No, not really, @VivianDeSmedt because I am already using `compile_commands.json`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: If you are satisfied with your answer maybe could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by installing llvm from brew,

Paying attention to the caveats, added the following in bashrc (or similar):

```sh
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"
```

and then adding this in lvim config:

```lua
local nvim_lsp = require("lspconfig")

nvim_lsp.clangd.setup {
    cmd = { "/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clangd", "--background-index" },
    root_dir = nvim_lsp.util.root_pattern("compile_commands.json", ".clangd"),
}
```

Edit: So the problem was using an old version of clangd, and having two versions of clang (one installed through Mason and other was the builtin). I installed llvm clangd and followed the above steps.